# Service fabric reliable collections and immutability

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I was reading an article here
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections/
It says "you MUST not modify an object once you have given it to a reliable collection."

Why is that the case? Can I not modify the object and add it back to reliable collection? Will it not overwrite the previous value?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you can modify the same object and write it back to reliable collection. But this approach is buggy. When you make changes to the object , the value is only modified locally and is not written to disk of primary and secondary replicas. Till you explicitly write the modified object back to reliable collection, the local copy of the object and persisted copy won't be same. So it is always a good practice, to treat the object as immutable and make modifications to deep copy of the object.

Answer (score 1):

In traditional .net collections, the Value from a keyed lookup in a dictionary (or a pop/peek from a queue) returns a pointer to an object on the heap.  When you modify this pointer, the value in the heap is modified. As a result the state is mutated in the dictionary.

Reliable collections are a facade around a much more complex interaction.  While it is true that the collection is in memory*, the reliable state manager is also in charge of replicating any changes to the secondary replicas.  The mechanism by which this occurs is calling CommitAsync on the ITransaction.

If you were to only mutate the in memory representation of an object, the change will never be replicated to secondary partitions, and undefined/unexpected behavior will result. (say when the active primary switches to a secondary) If you do call CommitAsync (even if you do a Get -> Modify -> Set), the transaction might fail to commit and the current in memory representation will differ from that of the secondary partitions and the on disk representation of the primary partition.  This again, will lead to undefined/unexpected behavior.

*In most cases, unless the size of the collection is bigger than available memory. In this case the values are paged from disk and only the keys and recently used values are held in memory.  In the future, I have heard talk around paging further in to blob storage when disk pressure increases.

Answer (score -2):

The full statement is:

> However, with reliable collections, this code exhibits the same
>   problem as already discussed: you MUST not modify an object once you
>   have given it to a reliable collection.

That statement is in the context of problems associated with working on reliable collections. When working with SF reliable dictionaries, the API will look like standard .NET dictionaries. Behind the scenes, it is doing more like managing the state. With this differentiation, we need to keep in mind common pitfalls when working with these data structures. In the first code demonstration, it will look like it will update the object but will not.  Later on in the article, it provided you the correct way of modifying an object in the reliable collection.